# Right syntax in C to define an array of 3D pointers

Tags: c

in a C program I need to define

```
float (*d_i)[3];
```

but later I realized that I need to define NMAX variables of this type. I tried with

```
   float (*d_i)[3][NMAX];
```

but it does not work.

what would be the right syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't guess. Just use a `typedef`.

```
typedef float (*someType)[3];

someType d_i[NMAX];
```

(In case you really don't want the `typedef`,

```
float (*d_i[NMAX])[3];
```

)

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef float array_of_3_floats[3];

array_of_3_floats *d_i;           /* what you have now */
array_of_3_floats d_ii[NMAX];     /* what I think you want */
array_of_3_floats (*d_iii)[NMAX]; /* maybe what you want */
```

Answer (score 0):

Is NMAX a constant? If not, the memory allocation should be done dynamically using malloc (or equivalent).